# Resizing image in javascript how to apply my code for mobile?

Tags: javascript

the resizing works while smalling site but wont work on responsive view and i couldnt understand its html css js code but the image on site scale is all done with js can you guys help me please

```
 function scaleImage(img, ctx) {
    var canvas = ctx.canvas;
    var hRatio = canvas.width / img.width;
    var vRatio = canvas.height / img.height;
    var ratio = Math.max(hRatio, vRatio);
    var centerShift_x = (canvas.width - img.width * ratio) / 2;
    var centerShift_y = (canvas.height - img.height * ratio) / 2;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(
      img,
      0,
      0,
      img.width,
      img.height,
      centerShift_x,
      centerShift_y,
      img.width * ratio,
      img.height * ratio
    );
  }
```

Comment: Here's a simple guide on asking a better question. What's the input? What's the expected behavior and what's the actual behavior?

Comment: Does your HTML include a meta tag for viewport? Worth noting as it can cause scaling issues. Whatever responsive CSS you're using that can affect the canvas should also be included.

Comment: Also, I hope you are not scaling down an image using canvas just to display it on mobile, because the browser is better at that than you and you still load just as much data...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.